# List of posts not displaying - django

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a post model and would like to view the posts in post_list. While creating the new post, it is redirecting to post_list but not displaying any post.
 Also, in my post_form I have rendered the fields manually by using django templates. I couldnt figure out where I have made the mistake. Can someone please help me out. Thanks

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    author              =       models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    slug                =       models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
```

Comment: Are there any `Post` instances in your db? What are their `published_date` (because I see you are filtering by that date) ?

Answer (score 1):

By default the `context_object_name` is `object_list`

Either you access your Posts list in `template` with `object_list`

```
{% for post in object_list %}
     {{ post }} <!-- with lowercase -->
{% endfor %}
```

Or you change the `context_object_name` to `post_list`, so that way you will be able to access the post list with `post_list` in template

```
class PostListView(ListView):
     model = Post
     context_object_name = 'post_list'
```

Comment: I have changed it to object_list in template but still it is not showing the contents like title or s_desc. Only displaying the published date

Comment: If you see `published_date`, that means `object_list` exists. the other fields might be empty

Comment: yea. It is not saving the data to tables. I mean the other fields are saved as blank.  How can I fix that ?

Comment: It's because your `input_name`s in form, are not correct, either you remove all the imputs html that you've created and use only the `form.as_p` or your utilize only your own html without `form.as_p` the first one is better

Comment: no need to create your own html, django `form.as_p` will generate everything, that's why you didn't get any value from some `fields`. if you get stuck, just edit your question by adding the `post_form` view

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use lowercase variable name in your `post_list.html`.

For instance, `{{ Post.title }}` should probably be lowercase `{{ post.title }}`.
There are a few places to change that.